# how can I parameterize a F# class

Tags: f#

The class below is a wrapper around an async MailboxProcessor that exposes
a few operations to C# assemblies. However, I don't want just a few

```
Map<string,int>
```

instances, I need several different Map<'K,'V> instances where 'K and 'V vary.
I hope I don't need a functor for that (it probably doesn't exist in F#).

```
module Flib.AsyncEvents
open System.Collections.Generic

type KVcoll = Map<string,int>
type Msg = Request of string * int option | Fetch of AsyncReplyChannel<KVcoll> | Clear

#nowarn "40"
type myAgent () = class
    let dictAgent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox->
        let dict = ref Map.empty
        let rec loop = async { 
            let! msg = inbox.Receive()       
            match msg with
            | Request (key, Some value) -> dict := Map.add key value !dict
            | Request (key, None) -> dict := Map.remove key !dict
            | Fetch(reply) -> reply.Reply(!dict)
            | Clear -> dict := Map.empty
            return! loop
            }
        loop)

    member this.add(key, value) = dictAgent.Post (Request (key, Some value))
    member this.del(key) = dictAgent.Post (Request(key, None))
    member this.fetch() = dictAgent.PostAndReply((fun reply -> Fetch(reply)), timeout = 9000)
    member this.lookup(key) = try 0, Map.find key (this.fetch()) // success
                              with | :? KeyNotFoundException -> -1, 0  // failure
    member this.size() = this.fetch().Count
    member this.clear() = dictAgent.Post (Clear)
    member this.print() =
           this.fetch() |> Map.iter (fun k v -> printfn "%s => %d" k v)
           printfn "done"
end
```

By the way, this is prototype quality code, clearly not as good as it can be.

Comment: Not related to your question but why the mutable (via `ref`) Map instead of a Dictionary which is already mutable by nature ?

Comment: because if a mutable dictionary is returned it cannot be read without a lock outside the dictAgent whereas a persistent map is always available to be read without preconditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but if you want to create a type that can be used with different types of values, you can define the class as generic:

```
type Msg<'K, 'V when 'K : comparison> = 
  | Request of 'K * 'V option 
  | Fetch of AsyncReplyChannel<Map<'K, 'V>> 
  | Clear

type MyAgent<'K, 'V when 'K : comparison> () = class
    let dictAgent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox->
        let dict : Map<'K, 'V> ref = ref Map.empty
        let rec loop = async { 
            // (same as before)
            }
        loop)
```

To make this work, you'll need to avoid code that restricts the type of keys and values to a particular type. In you case `lookup` was returning `0` as the default value and `print` was expecting strings. So you can replace those with something like:

```
member this.lookup(key) = Map.tryFind key (this.fetch()) 
member this.print() =
       this.fetch() |> Map.iter (fun k v -> printfn "%A => %A" k v)
       printfn "done"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I am still struggling with F# types and how to best use them to model requirements